# Is retro-programming on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes think about developing for retro-systems (e.g. C64 or DOS) just for fun. I wonder if there are related tags and these are on-topic here.

Or should I hope that retrocomputing.se will go live?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c64

Comment: Hey, it's good to know that. Not very encouraging though. Two questions with no answers.

Comment: You're on the unanswered tab.  Choose one of the other tabs to see all the questions.

Comment: Why would you think that those programming languages and techniques 'expire' somehow? What is the length of time, what is the usage graph, that determines when they expire? If you have a programming question, you should ask it here.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z80) contains some very interesting questions -- twice as much as on the ol' Commodore. The ZX Spectrum Rules! 

Comment: @Jongware well, [6502] has about the same as z80.

Comment: Also, one person's retro is another person's maintenance. :)

Comment: ^ while the specific language in the linked question was in fact a homework language, there's good answers there that answer this question for the general case.

Comment: retrocomputing is computing, anyway.

Comment: Like, nobody uses FORTRAN or COBOL nowadays. #retrocomputing

Comment: Wow, its been a very very very long time since I programmed on a c64.  That is if you can actually count manually typing in commands found in a magazine as programming. Its not retro, its archaeology!

Comment: I think that it's appropriate, and useful.

Comment: @sphanley How is that a duplicate of this question. Retro-programming doesn't inherently involve _rare programming languages_ are used. It's more about specific machine/µC contexts (and eventually emulators available for them nowadays).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I guess that's fair but it just seemed like the point of the question was the same, whether it was "rare" or "retro" languages -- are languages that are for one reason or the other not commonplace on-topic?

Comment: @sphanley My point is more about having the correct tags at hand (as there were mentioned [tag:z80], [tag:c64] or [tag:6502]) to narrow the context. Some of them also require to use a particular (rare) programming language/assembly code, but that's not the point of that question in general.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do you have appropriate tags at hand?

I'd say anything that's not unrelated to *programming* in certain contexts, should not be considered as *off-topic* here.

> *"Or should I hope that retrocomputing.se will go live?"*

SO is well suited for *retro-computing* questions, as long you give it enough context.

Comment: I don't have appropriate tags yet. I think one of them would be [retro] of course, but the target platform or language also can be a tag.

Comment: @purplehuman  A tag like [tag:retro] may come out as being _"too broad"_. Ask for specific machine context instead (you always can clarify within your question, instead of using a tag).

Comment: That's right, thanks. Apparently there's a c64 tag for example.

Comment: Machine specific tags would make it easier to select questions. I am probably not going to learn another system that is already obsolete, so I would only follow tags for systems I've programmed in the past.

Comment: I'm with @Patricia on this. I have seen some very interesting questions on the old Z80, primarily dealing with emulation. As this is the very chip I learned to program assembly for, it's still close to my heart.

Comment: I really thought you were going to say 
"SO is well suited for retro-computing questions, as long you give it enough *time*."

Comment: "I'd say anything that's not unrelated to programming in certain contexts, should not be considered as off-topic here." Dat quadruple negative!

Comment: @Boann Yeah, we germans are good with dat ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ We English speakers are not. Since you first posted this, I've wanted to change it to, "anything that's related to programming in certain contexts should be considered as on-topic here." I've held back because I feel like that's not exactly what you want to say, but a rewrite would be not unwarranted ;)

Comment: If you DON'T have an appropriate tag, then maybe going through the process of creating a tag may be appropriate, if it's specific enough to whatever you're looking at doing (but broad enough for potential future reuse by others).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot It was kind of intentional, I wanted everyone to read this sentence at least 3 times.

Comment: Read it three times and understand it once? Seems to defeat the purpose...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot _"Read it three times and understand it once?"_ That is, what gives you that wonderful feeling _the penny has dropped_ actually and you have learned something now (and where I wanted to steer it). Though not being a native english speaker, I'm aware of language constructs, grammatics, and how to use them for emphasis (may be _quadruple negation_ was just a bit of an overshoot here).